# Building a query string for a get request

Tags: haskell, networking, http-conduit

Suppose I have this function performing a get request:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C8

get :: String -> [(C8.ByteString, C8.ByteString)] -> IO (Response LC8.ByteString)
get url par = do
  request <- parseUrl url 
  res <- withManager $ httpLbs $ createReq request
  return res
  where
    createReq req = 
      req {
            method = methodGet
          , queryString = map (\(k, v) -> k ++ "&=" ++ v) par -- ????
          }
```

I believe there must a simpler way to create a query string. My method both is not simple and wrong as it doesn't care about "?" and "&" (there must be "?" in the beggining and must not be "&" at the end). So how do I create a query string for a get request from `[(C8.ByteString, C8.ByteString)]` ? Moreover, (++) can't be used with ByteString. But I haven't found any example which is surprising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use functions from [Network.HTTP.Types.URI](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-types-0.7.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Types-URI.html) present in `http-types` package. Infact, `http-types` is one of the dependency package for `http-conduit`.

```
λ> import Network.HTTP.Types.URI
λ> import Data.ByteString
λ> :set -XOverloadedStrings
λ> let getData = [("key1", Just "value1"), ("key2", Just "value2")] :: [(ByteString, Maybe ByteString)]
λ> renderQuery True getData
"?key1=value1&key2=value2"
λ> renderQuery False getData
"key1=value1&key2=value2"
```

See how the `Bool` value in `renderQuery` controls prepending `?` to the request.

**Update**: Starting from `http-client 0.3.6`, [Michael Snoyman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369198/michael-snoyman) has added this functionality in [setQueryString](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.3.6/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:setQueryString) as indicated by him in the comments.

Comment: Inspired by this question and answer, I just added a new function to http-client and http-conduit: [setQueryString](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.3.6/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:setQueryString).

Comment: Thanks, I see that you are not prepending `?` to the `Request` in that function. Any reasons for that ?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference either way, http-client will automatically add in a missing `?`. See: https://github.com/snoyberg/http-client/blob/master/http-client/Network/HTTP/Client/Request.hs#L355